# Mono TCP server listening but connection fails

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, server, mono

I have a C# program running on Mono on my Pi 3 and listening on port 8877. It's running Raspian and has no firewall as far as I can tell - I've also not installed one.

[image: netstat -pln]

But I cannot connect to it from my Windows PC, using telnet, that's on the same home network. SSH works fine, though.

[image: Telnet connection failed]

I also know the app is running as expected by reading a log it writes to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please stop using pictures, past in the text from the Raspberry Pi and format it as code! Use a port scanner from the Windows PC to chack whats open on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Why should I not use images? Why did you post this comment when it has been solved?

Comment: Pictures is hard to search in and some other could find a solution to their question it the text is searchable!

Comment: @MatsK That's a good point, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I the problem was with the C# app. It was listening on the local address:

`IPAddress.Loopback`

When apparently to be accessible on the network it needs to listen on:

`IPAddress.Any`